# Аналог CodeSniffer для Java

Tags: java, code-style

Я слышал, что для php существует такой инструмент как CodeSniffer: он проверяет код на соответствие определенным правилам и если они выполняются - допускает коммит в репозиторий. К этим правилам относится прецмущемтвенно codestyle и определенные соглашения (не использовать continue, например). Есть ли похожий инструмент для java?